# pendingTransactionsに滞留している謎のtransactionについて

Tags: ethereum

PrivateNetで開発しています
`eth.pendingTransactions`を実行すると、`to`に覚えのないアドレスが設定されたtransactionが多数発生します
`to`に設定されるアドレスは複数種類ありますが、`value`は同じ値が入っています
覚えのないアドレスに対し`getTransaction`を実行するとEthを保有しています
覚えがないだけにパスワードも不明ですが、'sendTransction'で抜いてみようとすると

```
Error: unknown account
```

現状coinbaseから流出しているようでまいっています

chaindata,lightchaindataフォルダを削除しgenesisi.jsonでinitからやり直しても同じ事象が起きます
何かご存知の方いらっしゃらないでしょうか

類似情報見つけました
https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/issues/17127
対処は今の所ポートの変更しか思いつかないです

Comment: コントラクトから別のコントラクトのpayable関数を呼んでいてそのコントラクトアドレスがtoに入っている可能性はありませんか？

Comment: gethをinitした直後からも発生するようになってしましました。コントラクトはデプロイすらしていません。タイミング的にはデプロイするために、coinbaseをunlockした途端に発生するようです。pendingTransactionsに入ってきます。

Comment: apt-get purge ehtereumのあとinitしましたが、再インストール後gethコンソールでこれまでの履歴が残っており、pendingTransactionsにも残っていました。

Comment: purgeの後にdatadirごと削除し再インストールしましたが事象変わらずです。coinbaseのアドレスしかないのに...

Comment: 何度もすみません。lockするとまた流出は止まり、pendingTransactionsには滞留することはありません。